# How to remove the word (chapter) from the bibliography page?

Tags: chapters

Can anyone help me please, to solve this issue. I am writing in the document class (report) and want to remove the word (chapter) from the bibliography page. I have found the below code but it does not serve me  because it removes any chapter word.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\huge}{\thechapter.}{20pt}{\huge\it}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Name of Chapter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Your write-up isn't very clear: You mention a bibliography page, but your code doesn't generate a bibliography. Please edit your posting so that the code actually generates the problem behavior you would like to fix.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to manually format this. The Bibliography itself appears without the **Chapter** word.

A basic file like this should be your starting point:

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Name of Chapter}

\cite{a1990}

\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{bibfilename}

\end{document}
```

And when I say *starting point*, I really mean this. The above does not
show you the `bibfilename.bib` which is a separate file.

Please study slowly either of the following and start-over:

- https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Bibliography_management_with_bibtex#!#The_bibliography_file
- https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management

And perhaps your best bet will be to get an old report and use that as a template.